# How can I CGFloat value that store in model in my view at .position modifier in Swift?

Tags: swiftui, drag-and-drop, position, cgfloat

I have a model for animals that contain animal name, image, position X and position Y. I try to use position X and position Y variable in .position modifier to drag and drop animal image in position X and position Y. the main problem is the .position modifier does not identify the CGFloat value (position X and position Y)

I try to call my position X and position Y by ForEach loop that is go throw all my animals model, create a variable for my model(animal) to access the position X and position Y value. when I try to print the animal.posx and animal.posy the printed value are 0.0 and 0.0.

This is my swift view:

```swift
@Query var OwnAnimal : [Kid_animal]

     ForEach(OwnAnimal, id: \.self) { animal in
                
                
                  
                        
                        if animal.Animal_drag == true
                        {
                            
                            Image(animal.animal_image).resizable()
                                .scaledToFit()
                                .frame(width: 80, height: 80)
                                .position(x: animal.posx, y: animal.posy)
                            
                        }
                        else {
                            Circle()
                                .fill(Color.white)
                                .opacity(0.4)
                                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                            
                                .position(x : animal.posx, y: animal.posy)
                                .onDrop(of: ["public.image"], isTargeted: nil) { providers, location in
                                    
                                    guard let provider = providers.first else {
                                        return false
                                    }
                                    
                                    if provider.canLoadObject(ofClass: UIImage.self) {
                                        _ = provider.loadObject(ofClass: UIImage.self) { image, error in
                                            if let image = image as? UIImage {
                                                
                                                let droppedImage = Image(uiImage: image)
                                                droppedImages[animal.animal_image] = droppedImage
                                                
                                            }else{
                                                
                                                
                                                
                                                withAnimation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 0.2)) {
                                                    droppedImages[animal.animal_image] = nil
                                                }
                                            }
                                            
                                        }
                                    }
                                    
                                    animal.Animal_drag = true
                                    return true
                                    
                                }
                                .overlay(
                                    
                                    droppedImages[animal.animal_image].map {
                                        $0.resizable()
                                            .scaledToFit()
                                            .frame(width: 80, height: 80)
                                            .position(x: animal.posx, y: animal.posy)
                                        
                                    }
                                    
                                    
                                )
                        }
                        
                    
                
            }
```

This is my model:

```
import SwiftData
import CoreGraphics
@Model
 class Kid_animal {
    var animal_name : String = ""
    var animal_image : String = ""
    var level : String = ""
    var animal_energy : String = ""
     var posx : CGFloat
     var posy : CGFloat
     var Animal_drag : Bool
     
     init(animal_name: String, animal_image: String, level: String, animal_energy: String,  posx: CGFloat , posy: CGFloat,Animal_drag : Bool) {
         self.animal_name = animal_name
         self.animal_image = animal_image
         self.level = level
         self.animal_energy = animal_energy
         self.posx = posx
         self.posy = posy
         self.Animal_drag = Animal_drag
         
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow the naming conventions, and for non optional properties you need the default value 0.0, for SwiftUI you would need to set the class to ObservedObject and @Published all the properties to be observed.

Try the above!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).